# Linear Regression on Pandas DataFrame using Sklearn ( IndexError: tuple index out of range)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, dataframe, linear-regression

I'm new to Python and trying to perform linear regression using sklearn on a pandas dataframe. This is what I did:

```
data = pd.read_csv('xxxx.csv')
```

After that I got a DataFrame of two columns, let's call them 'c1', 'c2'. Now I want to do linear regression on the set of (c1,c2) so I entered

```
X=data['c1'].values
Y=data['c2'].values
linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)
```

which resulted in the following error

```
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What's wrong here? Also, I'd like to know

1. visualize the result
2. make predictions based on the result?

I've searched and browsed a large number of sites but none of them seemed to instruct beginners on the proper syntax. Perhaps what's obvious to experts is not so obvious to a novice like myself.

Comment: It could be a data problem.  It may be helpful to provide a representative sample of your csv.  Separately, looking at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html, at the bottom they create their regression object (regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()), then call rers.fit(X, Y).

Comment: Regarding your PS: I notice that many beginners questions get down voted due to not formatting their questions according to SO practices: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 61):

Let's assume your csv looks something like:

```
c1,c2
0.000000,0.968012
1.000000,2.712641
2.000000,11.958873
3.000000,10.889784
...
```

I generated the data as such:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets, linear_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

length = 10
x = np.arange(length, dtype=float).reshape((length, 1))
y = x + (np.random.rand(length)*10).reshape((length, 1))
```

This data is saved to test.csv (just so you know where it came from, obviously you'll use your own).

```
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', index_col=False, header=0)
x = data.c1.values
y = data.c2.values
print x # prints: [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9.]
```

You need to take a look at the shape of the data you are feeding into `.fit()`.

Here `x.shape = (10,)` but we need it to be `(10, 1)`, see [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).  Same goes for `y`. So we reshape:

```
x = x.reshape(length, 1)
y = y.reshape(length, 1)
```

Now we create the regression object and then call `fit()`:

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
regr.fit(x, y)

# plot it as in the example at http://scikit-learn.org/
plt.scatter(x, y,  color='black')
plt.plot(x, regr.predict(x), color='blue', linewidth=3)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.show()
```

See sklearn linear regression [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html).
[image]

Answer (score 17):

## Dataset

[image]

## Importing the libraries

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

## Importing the dataset

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('1.csv')
X = dataset[["mark1"]]
y = dataset[["mark2"]]
```

## Fitting Simple Linear Regression to the set

```
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X, y)
```

## Predicting the  set results

```
y_pred = regressor.predict(X)
```

## Visualising the  set results

```
plt.scatter(X, y, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X, regressor.predict(X), color = 'blue')
plt.title('mark1 vs mark2')
plt.xlabel('mark1')
plt.ylabel('mark2')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: IMHO, `X = dataset[["mark1"]]` clearer than `reshape`!

Comment: Just to mention that using `plt.plot(X, regressor.predict(X), color = 'blue')` didn't work for me, I had to use `dataset["mark1"]` instead of `dataset[["mark1"]]` for the `x` otherwise I got a `TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), None)' is an invalid key` error.

Answer (score 8):

I post an answer that addresses exactly the error that you got:

> IndexError: tuple index out of range

### **Scikit-learn expects 2D inputs. Just reshape the `X` and `Y`.**

**Replace:**

```
X=data['c1'].values # this  has shape (XXX, ) - It's 1D
Y=data['c2'].values # this  has shape (XXX, ) - It's 1D
linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)
```

**with**

```
X=data['c1'].values.reshape(-1,1) # this  has shape (XXX, 1) - it's 2D
Y=data['c2'].values.reshape(-1,1) # this  has shape (XXX, 1) - it's 2D
linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)
```

Answer (score 6):

> make predictions based on the result?

To predict,

```
lr = linear_model.LinearRegression().fit(X,Y)
lr.predict(X)
```

> Is there any way I can view details of the regression?

The LinearRegression has `coef_` and `intercept_` attributes.

```
lr.coef_
lr.intercept_
```

show the slope and intercept.

Answer (score 0):

You really should have a look at the docs for the `fit` method which you can view [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.fit)

For how to visualize a linear regression, play with the example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#example-linear-model-plot-ols-py). I'm guessing you haven't used ipython (Now called jupyter) much either, so you should definitely invest some time into learning that. It's a great tool for exploring data and machine learning. You can literally copy/paste the example from scikit linear regression into an ipython notebook and run it

For your specific problem with the `fit` method, by referring to the docs, you can see that the format of the data you are passing in for your `X` values is wrong.

Per the docs,
"X : numpy array or sparse matrix of shape [n_samples,n_features]"

You can fix your code with this

```
X = [[x] for x in data['c1'].values]
```

Comment: Thank you, Tommy. Is there any way I can view details of the regression?

Comment: Most likely. What details would you like?