# How to speed up two nested for loops in big dataset

Tags: python, performance, loops, for-loop, parallel-processing

I am working on a 600.000 x 128 dataset, arranged in the following form with a hierarchical index (see left):

```
                    Var1     Var2     ...                                     Var1_mean  Var2_mean     ...          
    ID     Date                                               ID     Date          
    1      2017-12  1        0.1                              1      2017-12  2          0.3
    1      2018-01  2        0.3                              1      2018-01  2          0.3
    1      2018-02  3        0.5            -->               1      2018-02  2          0.3
    2      2018-01  2        0.2                              2      2018-01  3          0.15
    2      2018-02  4        0.1                              2      2018-02  3          0.15
```

Now for all 55.000 customers (= unique IDs) I want to replace the values per customer in selected variables with the averages per customer, stored in new variables (Variable name + '_mean', see right).

I wrote a function to do that, but it takes 4+ hours, even after trying to parallelize the task. I tried:

```
    identifiers = set(df_raw_sort.index.get_level_values(0)) # unique IDs

    def avg_per_customer(column): 
       df_raw_sort.loc[:, column + '_mean'] = 0 # Create new col
       for unique in identifiers: 
          meanvalue = np.mean(df_raw_sort[column].loc[(unique)])
          df_raw_sort.loc[(unique), column + '_mean'] = meanvalue

    Parallel(n_jobs=2, verbose=10)(delayed(avg_per_customer)(col) for col in transform)
    # transforms selected columns (= transform)
```

What could I do to speed this thing up?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this

> df_raw_sort[variable_name_mean] = df_raw_sort[variable_name].groupby(df_raw_sort[‘ID’]).transform(‘mean’)

[Referred answer from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244952/python-pandas-create-new-column-with-groupby-sum)

Comment: Thanks a lot! After getting rid of the hierarchical index, it worked in some seconds!
Would there be any equally easy way to calculate the slope of a linear regression (like scipy.stats.linregress) instead of the average? So in the case of above:
ID1: 1
ID2: -1

Thank you, Avinash

Comment: You are welcome. I have never calculated linear regression but have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46754476/2196290