# How do you upload dataset and read it on python and do a simple linear regression on Python?

Tags: python

How do I upload dataset with file name: Users/zeinabhassano/Documents/Master's_thesis/Gender Inequality/Labor data/ILO modelled estimates/updated/employment by sex and age - ilo modelled estimates (thousands) - annual.xlsx?

How do I run simple regressions where Y is the employment value and X is a dummy variable if its a male or female?

I tried to do the following but I couldn't display the data. And need help with the simple regression.

```
#Read the excel file
import pandas as pd

#construct the full path to your excel file
excel_file_path = "/Users/zeinabhassano/Documents/Master's_thesis/Gender Inequality/Labor data/ILO modelled estimates/updated/employment by sex and age - ilo modelled estimates (thousands) - annual.xlsx"

#read the excel file
print(excel_file_path)
```

Comment: You want to *download* or *upload* said xlsx file? If latter where it should be delivered?

Answer (score 1):

from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/pandas-read_excel-reading-excel-file-in-python

```
import pandas
excel_file_path = "/Users/zeinabhassano/Documents/Master's_thesis/Gender Inequality/Labor data/ILO modelled estimates/updated/employment by sex and age - ilo modelled estimates (thousands) - annual.xlsx"

excel_data_df = pandas.read_excel(excel_file_path, sheet_name='is this your homework?')#on your classmates name?

# print whole sheet data
print(excel_data_df)
```

cool google result
[Linear Regression on Pandas DataFrame using Sklearn ( IndexError: tuple index out of range)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29934083/linear-regression-on-pandas-dataframe-using-sklearn-indexerror-tuple-index-ou)